# When does SKErrorClientInvalid occur?

Tags: ios, storekit

The documentation has this to say about SKErrorClientInvalid:

> Indicates that the client is not allowed to perform the attempted action.

Does anybody know the circumstances under which this error actually occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get this error when a user wants to buy a non-consumable item that he has already purchased but refuses to restore it.

- User requests a product
- Confirm your in-app purchase
- [Buy] button pressed
- You have already purchased this. Tap OK to download it again for free.
- [Cancel] button pressed
- ---> Program gets SKErrorClientInvalid

Comment: I also get it, when a user tries to repurchase a non-renewing subscription.

Comment: @NicTesla How does the store know if the user is simply renewing the subscription rather than mistakenly purchasing it twice?

Comment: @Robert I testet this with a non-renewable subscription within 15 minutes repurchasementtime, so this is why i guess, the store asked me as the test-user, if i want to repurchase this item again. Usually it doesn't since the documentation tells us so. Sorry for that confusing comment.